# How to get a combined functionality of $geoWithin and $near in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

We all know `$near` searches nearest to farthest from a point(if a point is given) whereas `$geoWithin` searches within a polygon area. How to obtain a combined functionality where all the co-ordinates inside a polygon area nearest to a point is obtained?

Comment: geoWithin and geoNear differ exactly for the same reasons that you want to combine them i.e sorted results and geometric regularity of the search boundary.

I can think of using $geoWithin first, and then parse the results to measure the distance between the reference point and result item and sort by that field. It may not work well with really large result sets though.

Comment: That would take a too much time if done manually. If we have the sorting functionality within mongodb, why no utilize it there itself?